# Infinite loop in my simple assembly program

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I am learning loops and jumps in assembly and I try to make a simple loop. I want the `printf` command to be called 10 times. I have set the `counter` variable to 1. I have also set `%edx` to 1 and then I increment it for every iteration. If it is equal to 10, then we should exit the loop. But now the loop is infinite. I have debugged with `gdb` and `%edx` seems to be overwritten in the `printf` function. That is why I `push %edx` to the stack and the `pop` it back after the `printf` call, but it doesn't work. What have I missed?

```
.section .data
output:
    .asciz "Value is %d\n"
val1:
    .int 123
counter:
    .int 1
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    nop
    movl counter, %edx   # start at 1
gohere:
    movl val1, %ebx      # move value 123 to %ebx
    pushl %edx           # push %edx to stack
    pushl %ebx           # push %ebx to stack 
    pushl $output
    call printf          # call printf
    popl %edx            # pop %edx value
    inc %edx
    cmp $10, %edx        # if %edx is less than 10...
    jl gohere            # ... go to gohere, otherwise exit

    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Does it work without the printf call?

Comment: printf() is a C-function that uses the cdecl calling convention.  Which requires you to pop the arguments you pushed.  So popl %edx does not actually restore the edx register value and the stack is imbalanced.  Add two pops.

Comment: Oh, I added `popl %edx` just as many times as I push values to the stack and it worked! Look at my edits in the code above. But it seems quiet ugly to just pop values many times like that. Isn't there any easier approach?

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because if you edit the question to contain the solution given in an answer (such as adding to `popl` instructions), the answer becomes meaningless for future readers. For that reason the essential content of questions (such as the code) should not be edited to match the answers.

Answer (score 2):

you pushed `output` as the last push so the first pop will pop `output`. it is Stack and it is LIFO. in your code `output` will be in `edx` after you pop it.
to solve it put two pops before `popl edx`:

```
popl output
popl ebx
```

Comment: Yeah, I notices that just seconds ago. :-) As I asked in my comment above: Isn't there any easier approach than to pop the values as many times as you pushed them? Can't I just point to the place in the stack directly to pop the value to %edx?

Comment: ofcourse you can, it's assembly and you can point any place in your memory. but it is more complex than two pops (you should point to 2 bytes after your stack base). Data Structure Principle says don't do this

Comment: `output` seems to be 13 bytes (13 characters) and `val1` is 4 byte integer. If I do `-17(%esp)` I should be able to directly set the value of -17(%esp) to %edx, but I guess I have calculated the amount of bytes the wrong way, becaues it dosen't work.

Comment: Yes, but the address (offset) of "output" is only 4 bytes. Try `addl $8, %esp` after the call - then you should be able to `popl %edx` as intended. (I'm not good at AT&T stntax, so may have screwed this up)